# Can't create PostGis extension on PostgreSQL database?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, homebrew, postgis

I'm trying to create a postgis extension on my PostgreSQL database for a Django project, but when I run `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` I get this error:

`ERROR:  extension "postgis" has no installation script nor update path for version "3.0.1"`

I installed all the dependencies with Homebrew on macOS, and this database is not on the 'postgres' user, it's on my own superuser.

Homebrew Dependency Versions

- postgresql@12.2
- postgis@3.0.1
- gdal@2.4.4
- geos@3.8.1
- proj@7.0.0

Any help is appreciated!! Been working on this issue for the last week.

Comment: Are you required to install it directly in macOS?  You may find it easier (and more portable) to use Docker for this.

Comment: From: https://postgis.net/install/ :
Homebrew users can just run “brew install postgis” and tends to be a favorite for more advanced users since there are brew scripts for most of the popular PostgreSQL extensions, __not always present in other Mac distributions__.
Sorry, cannot do more.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could determine, this is likely due to a versioning error between postgres and postgis. It seems that `brew install postgis` will install the most recent version of postgres and make the postgis extension available only to that version. I got it to work by uninstalling previous versions of postgres and doing a clean install of the most recent version (the one the postgis is expecting). You can find the version postgis is expecting by searching the [homebrew site](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/postgis#default).

First, **back up your database** if you need to save your data. (See [pgdump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/backup-dump.html).)

Next, stop all of the running postgres server instances. Try the following:

- Use `brew services list` to see all postgres services running. Use `brew services stop [name]` to stop any listed postgres services that are running.
- Use `sudo lsof -i :5432` to confirm that no database server is listening on port 5432. (This is the default port for postgres.) If you see any results, use `sudo kill [pid]` to stop the server.

Now, uninstall postgres:

`brew uninstall --force postgresql`

Then delete the database file (this removes your data so **make a backup**):

`rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres`

Now you can follow [these setup instructions](https://www.robinwieruch.de/postgres-sql-macos-setup) to install postgres. Note that the default superuser of your database will be the one you use to do the `initdb` command. Thus, you may want to use `sudo -u postgres` before doing the `initdb` to keep the default database superuser name "postgres". (See more about default users [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/database-roles.html).)